# Simple method to prove $a^3+b^3=1$ has no integer solutions if $ab\neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Any simple method to prove $a^3+b^3=1$ has no integer solutions if $ab\neq 0$ that does not involve Fermat's last theorem?

Comment: it is rational solutions that correspond to FLT

Comment: @WillJagy, I agree. I was trying to avoid touching this beast

Comment: the exponent 3 case of FLT is taught as an application of Eisenstein integers,  similar to Gaussian integers. Not so bad.

Comment: I concur. Euler's proof was also quite elementary and easy to understand

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$1 = a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = (a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)$$
implies $a+b=\pm 1$ and so $(a+b)^2 - 3ab = 1 - 3ab \not\in \{-1,1\}$ if $ab \ne 0$

Comment: very elegant! Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am going to try to see if this method applies to all odd prime $p$

Comment: Does not apply to all  prime $p$: $3^3+(-2)^2=19$

Comment: @KeithBackman I think they mean the equation $a^p+b^p=1$. Also, you probably mean $(-2)^3$, not $(-2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 -ab + b^2)=1$

The only factors of $1$ are either $1\cdot 1$ or $-1 \cdot (-1)$.

So we must have $a+b = a^2 - ab + b^2 =\pm 1$.

And that just won't work unless $ab=0$.

It would follow that $b= \pm 1 -a$

And therefore  $a^2 - a(\pm 1 - a) + (\pm 1 - a) = \pm 1$ so

$a^2+a^2 \mp a -a \pm 1 = \pm 1$

SO either $2a^2 -2a+1=1$ or $2a^2 -1 = -1$ so

$2a(a-1) = 0;b= 1-a$ or $2a^2 = 0;b = -1-a$.

So we have either $a=0$ and $b=1$.  Of $a =1$ and $b =0$.  Or $a=0$ and $b =  -1$.

In all three cases we must have $ab = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ab\neq 0$
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=1$$ Therefore $a,b$ cannot have the same signs, then $$ab < 0$$ Hence $$a^2-ab+b^2>1$$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Tedious (and therefore somewhat inferior) alternative approach that focuses on the minimum difference between distinct cubes.

Prove that the following is impossible:

- $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$
- $a \neq 0 \neq b.$
- $a^3 + b^3 = 1.$

For $c,k \in \Bbb{Z},~$ let $f(c,k) = (3c^2k + 3ck^2 + k^3).$

$\underline{\text{Lemma 1}}$ 
$(c,k \in \Bbb{Z^+}) ~\implies ~f(c,k) \neq 1.$ 
Proof : 
$f(1,1) = 7.$ 
$(c \geq 1) ~\implies~ (c^2 \geq 1).$ 
$(k \geq 1) ~\implies~ (k^2 \geq 1 ~~~\text{and}~~~ k^3 \geq 1).$ 
Therefore,
$~~(c \geq 1 ~~~\text{and}~~~ k \geq 1) ~\implies~ f(c,k) \geq f(1,1).$

$\underline{\text{Lemma 2}}$ 
$(c,k \in \Bbb{Z^+}) ~\implies ~ \{[(c+k)^3 - c^3] \neq 1\}.$ 
Proof : 
$[(c+k)^3 - c^3] = f(c,k)$.
Invoke Lemma 1.

---

If $a,b$ both positive, then the minimum value of $a^3 + b^3$ is $2$. 
If $a,b$ both negative, then the maximum value of $a^3 + b^3$ is $-2$.

Therefore, $~~~~a \in \Bbb{Z^+},~ b \in \Bbb{Z^-},~~~~$ or vice versa.

Since the equation in dispute, $1 = a^3 + b^3$, is symmetric with respect to $a$ and $b$, 
without loss of generality,
$~~a \in \Bbb{Z^+},~ b \in \Bbb{Z^-}$

Let $c = -b \implies$

- $c \in \Bbb{Z^+}~~$ and
- $1 = a^3 + b^3 = a^3 - c^3$.

This implies that $a > c.$ 
Therefore, $~~~\exists k \in \Bbb{Z^+}~~~$ such that $~~~a = (c + k)$. 
Invoke Lemma 2.